# Dashboard in Python to the customer upload the database

Tags: python, dashboard

People, pls, help me.
I have to create a dashboard system in Python for a customer but he doesn't wanna to share his database because is "top secret"!
Is it possible to do it but with some database upload GUI?
I mean, I create the system of dashboard, prepare all ETL using a parameter (DF) but DF = database uploaded.
Got it?

I didn't try anything.